# Salesforce DX: null data source deploy error

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

When deploying to by Partial Sandbox after converting my source into a deployable format, I am getting the following error:

`Deploying /var/folders/h2/tl008ns11qj1t8m4gqysfvgr0000gn/T/mdapipkg.zip...
ERROR:  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getInputStream null data source. Error Id: 1424718776-14820 (236658248).`

I have converted my previous source and deployed multiple times in the past couple weeks and have deployed to the same org without any problems. I even moved the HEAD of my Git tree to a previous deploy that was successful and I'm still getting the same error!

It therefore doesn't seem an issue with my actual source, but maybe some weird syncing issue between the partial org's metadata and that which I have locally (although there haven't been any changes in the Partial Sandbox since the last deploy).

Has anybody run into a similar issue?

*Edit*
Here is the log that I pulled from .sfdx/sfdx.log:

`{"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Jons-MacBook-Pro.local","pid":18838,"level":50,"msg":"[ false,\n  '{\"message\":\"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getInputStream null data source. Error Id: 464995799-13097 (236658248)\",\"status\":1,\"stack\":\"soapenv:Server: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getInputStream null data source. Error Id: 464995799-13097 (236658248)\\\\n    at module.exports.HttpApi.getError (/Users/jduelfer/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/jsforce/lib/http-api.js:250:13)\\\\n    at /Users/jduelfer/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/jsforce/lib/http-api.js:95:22\\\\n    at tryCallOne (/Users/jduelfer/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)\\\\n    at /Users/jduelfer/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15\\\\n    at flush (/Users/jduelfer/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)\\\\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)\\\\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)\",\"name\":\"soapenv:Server\",\"warnings\":[]}' ]","time":"2017-10-18T17:57:58.510Z","v":0}`

Comment: It has a gack ID so you might want to reach to salesforce support !

Comment: Yeah I might contact them to see what the exact error is. I am currently going through my commits and I have found that some deploys work. It seems to have to do with static resources. Will update if I find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

After going back through all my commits and using the .forceignore file to exclude certain types of files, I found that the problem was with some static resources. I rebuilt the static resources from the state of the commit, redeployed, and everything worked.

Although I'm not 100% sure, it seems to have been some dependency issue that wasn't showing a helpful error.